# Lifting idempotents in semiperfect rings $R$ modulo ideals other than $\mathrm{rad}(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is semiperfect by definition, if $R/\mathrm{rad}(R)$ is semisimple and all idempotents of $R/\mathrm{rad}(R)$ can be lifted to idempotents in $R$. I wonder whether this lifting is also possible with respect to other ideals than $\mathrm{rad}(R)$ in a semiperfect ring.

There is a homological characterization of semiperfect rings as those rings for which all finitely generated modules have projective covers. I am quite sure that the proof of that characterization also shows, that we can lift idempotents modulo any ideal of $R$ contained in $\mathrm{rad}(R)$.

Can anyone confirm this observation? If it is true, is there another proof which is closer to the definition of semiperfect rings? I would also be happy to see a reference.

Comment: I'm working from memory, but I think whether or not an idempotent $e+I$ of $R/I$ lifts is governed by $(e+I)R/I$ having an $R$ projective cover. Perhaps you can prove or disprove this and maybe use that to formulate a proof.

Comment: @rschwieb: This would mean that we can lift idempotents modulo any ideal of an semiperfect ring. I don't know whether this is true. To adapt the usual proof (wrt. $\mathrm{rad}(R)$), we also need that the canonical epimorphism $R \to R/I$ is superfluous, i.e. $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$.

Comment: it's highly possible my memory needs correcting, like maybe what I said only applies to $I=J(R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple argument why we can lift idempotents modulo any ideal $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$ provided that we can lift idempotents modulo $\mathrm{rad}(R)$:

Let $e' \in R/I$ be any idempotent. Then we can lift the idempotent $e' + \mathrm{rad}(R)$ to an idempotent $e \in R$. Let $\overline{x}$ denote reduction modulo $I$ for any $x \in R$. Of course $e'$ and $\overline{e}$ are not necessarily identical, but they are isomorphic since they have the same image in $R/\mathrm{rad}(R)$. For the same reason, $\overline{1-e}$ and $1-e'$ are isomorphic, hence $e'$ and $\overline{e}$ are even conjugated in $R/I$. Let $\overline{a} \in (R/I)^\times$ such that $(\overline{a})^{-1} \cdot \overline{e} \cdot \overline{a} = e'$. Since $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$, we have $a \in R^\times$. Now $a^{-1} e a \in R$ is an idempotent lift of $e'$.

Actually, in a semiperfect ring it is even possible to lift idempotents modulo any left ideal [1].

[1] Nicholson, W. Keith. "Lifting idempotents and exchange rings." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 229 (1977): 269-278.

Comment: could you tell me what $e'$ and $\overline{e}$ are isomorphic means? I don't know the meaning of two elements are isomorphic.

Comment: @Daisy Idempotents $e,f \in R$ are isomorphic if $Re \cong Rf$ as left modules, or equivalently, $eR \cong fR$ as right modules.

Comment: In short, the argument is: if $\overline{e}$ and $\overline{f}$ are conjugated in $R/\mathrm{rad}(R)$ then $e$ and $f$ are conjugated in $R$. This holds in particular, if $\overline{e} = \overline{f}$.

Comment: so you mean $e'R/I \cong \overline{e}R/I$ and $(1-\overline{e})R/I \cong (1-e')R/I$,then how do you get $e'$ and $\overline{e}$ are conjugated?

Comment: @Daisy These isomorphisms define an isomorphism of $R/I$ which is given as left multiplication with a unit. The idempotents are conjugated by that unit.

Comment: I know, thank you very much.